# How to iterate from 0 to sys.maxint using a for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to iterate from 0 to sys.maxint but getting a 'MemoryError'. How should I be doing this ?.

Here is the simple code snippet.

```
for i in range(sys.maxint):
  a = 1
```

ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
MemoryError

Comment: Use [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange). It supports iteration till `sys.maxint` in CPython.

Comment: Use `xrange` (or switch to python3).

Comment: in case `a = 1` is there just as a placeholder to make the for loop work, be aware you can use `pass` as a "do nothing" statement instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python 2, the range keyword constructs a list containing all of the numbers in range you specify. So if you want to create a range up to `2**31-1`, it has to allocate space for `4*(2**31-1)` bytes (about 8.5 Gb). You might not have that much ram.

And `2**31-1` assumes you are using 32 bit python. With 64 bit python, maxint is `2**63-1`. You definitely *do not* have that much ram (`8*(2**63-1)` = about 73 million Tb).

If you want to range over a set of numbers in Python 2 and don't want to ahead-of-time construct the full list of those numbers (and thereby use that much ram), you can use `xrange` instead of `range`. The semantics are the same, but it returns a lazy iterator instead of a list.

Even if you do use `xrange`, it will still take forever to count up to `2**63-1`, but that's a different problem, and may not matter if you plan on breaking out of the for loop sooner than that. Just be aware of this during application development.

Final note, in Python 3, `xrange` is gone, and `range` is the function for constructing a lazy iterator. To get the equivalent of `range` in Python 2, you would do `list(range(v))`